# In a graph search query, is it possible to retrieve per each listItem, their parent name?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, microsoft-graph, graph

I make a POST query to /search Graph API, with the following body:

```
{
    "requests": [    
    {
        "entityTypes": [
            "listItem"
        ],
        "query": {
            "queryString": "*"
        },
        "fields": [
            "bodyPreview",
            "contentclass",
            "contentType",
            "createdBy",
            "createdDateTime",
            "department",
            "description",
            "displayName",
            "end",
            "file",
            "filetype",
            "folder",
            "from",
            "givenName",
            "lastModifiedDateTime",
            "listItemId",
            "name",
            "parentReference",
            "phones",
            "pictureThumbnailURL",
            "refinableString02",
            "replyTo",
            "sender",
            "size",
            "start",
            "subject",
            "surname",
            "title",
            "userPrincipalName",
            "webUrl"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As a response, I get different listItems from different lists inside my SharePoint tenant.

Is there a way (a field or something) to get into my response the name of the list each item belongs to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `path` property in `fields` array in request body. It will give you the URL of the list. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: or use `listid` to get unique ID (GUID) of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there is no managed property available for SharePoint "list name".

However, you can try using `path` or `listid` properties in `fields` array in request body which will give you some information related to your SharePoint list, like:

```
"fields": [
  "path",
  "listid",
  "title"
]
```

**Example**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ganesh, listid is exactly what I was looking for!